# jQuery masking working with jQuery 1.5 but not https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js

Tags: php, jquery, masking

So I am building a simple form that is using the bootstrap. Bootstrap wants to reference https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js as its core jQuery. When I reference that my bootstrap works but not my masking. It baulks at

```
 $(".phone").mask is not a function
```

If i change the jQuery reference to ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js it works just fine. I need them both to run on the same library. Any thoughts on what is hanging up the filter? It works for the validation just not the masking. Thanks!

Test Page: http://iupui.edu/~ofapd/registration/indexDirect.php?id=1165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rights. See in `js/jquery.maskedinput.js`:

```
 var pasteEventName = ($.browser.msie ? 'paste' : 'input') + ".mask";
 // TypeError: $.browser is undefined
```

See here [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed). Since `1.9` `$.browser` is removed. In first case https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js  you loading `1.10` - it doesnt work. But in second `1.5` - its works. Read about migration and compatibility.

Comment: With your reference i was able to track down the issue in the code and find a minified version online that is 1.9 complaint. http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

Answer (score 1):

The linked test site appears to be using an old version of jquery.maskedinput.js (1.2.2) which is not compatible with later versions of jQuery. Try the [latest version](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin) (currently 1.3.1).